# How do I change the display range of the x-axis when building my own specialized scatter plot GEOM?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am extending ggplot2 by building my own specialized scatter plot GEOM. Suppose that the input column that is mapped to the x aesthetic has a range of 0 to 1000. If I want to give the user of my GEOM an option to set the range of the x-axis to display, how do I do that without having to subset the data?

```
StatTimeLine <- ggproto("StatTimeLine", Stat,
                         required_aes = c("x"),
                         default_aes = aes(),
                         compute_group = function(data, scales, xmin, xmax) {
                           if (substr(xmin,1,1)=="-")
                             xmin <- as.Date(-1*as.numeric(difftime(substr(xmin, 2, nchar(xmin)), "0000-01-01")), origin="0000-01-01")
                           else
                             xmin <- as.Date(xmin, origin="0000-01-01")

                           if (substr(xmax,1,1)=="-")
                             xmax <- as.Date(-1*as.numeric(difftime(substr(xmax, 2, nchar(xmax)), "0000-01-01")), origin="0000-01-01")
                           else
                             xmax <- as.Date(xmax, origin="0000-01-01")
                           data <- data[data$x >= xmin & data$x <= xmax, ]
                           data
                         })
```

Comment: How is this different from using `xlim`?

Comment: It wouldn't be, but assuming we ain't allowed to use that.

Comment: I've added the code. But my code is just a stat_* that subsets the data. I don't want to have to subset the data, because I'll be adding at least another GEOM that will be for annotation purposes. So I've got the first geom that will take the xmin and xmax parameters, which is fine. But I don't want to have to input these parameters again when I add the annotation layer. Currently, the annotation layer also uses the same stat_* as the main layer.

Comment: @oahz If you don't want to subset the data repeatedly, why not subset it before passing the result to `ggplot()`? All geom layers inherit from the top level by default. Putting more information into your question, with a full reproducible example *and all the constraints you face*, would help us understand the situation better.